# How to Customize Navigation Bar of Facebook Login Screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, user-interface, facebook-login

[image: Login with facebook screen]

I use this swift code to login to Facebook from within my app:

```
   PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(["public_profile","user_about_me","email"]) { (user :PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true)
        if user != nil {
            self.getFacebookUserInfo()
        }
```

I want to customize the navigation bar of the Facebook login screen. How should I change my code to make this happen?

Comment: i dont think you can do that as it is a part of fb sdk

Comment: @WizKid i want to customise navigation bar of attached screen

Comment: That is not possible